compiler generated assembler
A question about compiler generated assembler:
My to-be-optimized main loop includes two memory accesses instead of register.
loop:
mov xmm, mem  // pre-calculated value pushed on the stack
pxor xmm, value_in_RO_data
...
jmp loop

I used gcc -O2, and using regs instead of mem should be the foremost measure, imo!
My loop is only a few ops, its a leaf proc and all other xmm are free.
it should be:
loop_init:
mov xmm1, mem
mov xmm2, ro-data;
loop:
use it...
jmp loop

Why this blunder and is there a hint to circumvent it?
PS: I checked again - it maybe not so leaf: the init loop has seek+read. And xmm are surely not saved.
... but nevertheless should the reload occur bevore the main loop!

What have I done:
My program is C++. I check the assembler output for optimizations. Two (imho pointless) memory accesses in my main loop are not acceptable!

Update:
An MWE is not trivial, but here are the key lines:
.L944:
        movdqu  xmm0, XMMWORD PTR -15[rsi+rdx]  # accepted next data load
        pcmpeqb xmm0, XMMWORD PTR [rsp]  # pre-calc val => should be in a reg!
# calced on the func entry, gcc push it and refuse to reload before use in main loop

        pxor    xmm0, XMMWORD PTR .LC41[rip]  # ro data => dito  (__m128i -1)
# a neg before movemask: _mm_movemask_epi8(~ val), but dito
 
        pmovmskb        ecx, xmm0
        test    ecx, ecx
        jne     .L943  # found, exit loop
        sub     rdx, 16
        cmp     rax, rdx
        jne     .L944  # my main loop

... maybe its because this is not a pure load, but a cmp and a xor (neg) action?
But reg is reg and mem is mem, the former is faster - or not anymore?

Update: (a tip from Peter Cordes)
A code change does the trick:
for (Size i = staticSize - 1 + diff, m; i >= 0; i-=16) {
        Quad turbo = _mm_loadu_si128((Quad*) (buffer + i - 15));
        turbo = _mm_cmpeq_epi8(turbo, lead);

//---        
        if (! (m = _mm_movemask_epi8(~ turbo))) {
                continue;
        }
        here = i - 15 + _bit_scan_reverse(m);
        goto done;

//===
        
        if ((m = _mm_movemask_epi8(turbo)) != 0xFFFF) {
                here = i - 15 + _bit_scan_reverse((Word) ~ m);
                goto done;
        }
//+++
}
done:

This leads to a very satisfying:
.L943:
        sub     rax, 16
        cmp     rax, rcx
        je      .L942  # jmp out
.L946:  # jmp in
        movdqu  xmm0, XMMWORD PTR -15[rsi+rax]
        pcmpeqb xmm0, xmm1  # pre-loaded
        pmovmskb        edx, xmm0
        cmp     edx, 65535
        je      .L943  # main loop
        not     edx
        movzx   edx, dx
        bsr     edx, edx
        lea     eax, -15[rdx+rax]
        test    eax, eax

Here is a starting point if you want to fiddle it out at godbolt:
#include <x86gprintrin.h>
#include <emmintrin.h>
#include <x86intrin.h>

const int max = 0x100000;
unsigned char buf[max];

__m128i lead = _mm_set1_epi8(24);

void func()
{
        int here = -1;

        for (long int i = max - 1, m; i >= 0; i-=16) {
                __m128i turbo = _mm_loadu_si128((__m128i*) (buf + i - 15));
        
                turbo = _mm_cmpeq_epi8(turbo, lead);
        
                if (! (m = _mm_movemask_epi8(~ turbo))) {
                        continue;
                }
        
                here = i - 15 + __bsrd(m);
                break;
        }
}

It's amazing what a small change can do!

Hard to say without seeing enough code to reproduce the issue.  Please state which compiler version and flags you used and provide the C++ source code you compiled or at least a [mcve] so others can have a look at what the compiler is doing.

Usually when GCC reloads something, it's because it can't prove that a store in the loop wasn't to the same address.  __restrict can help to promise that things don't overlap.  But that's surprising for a value in .rodata; it should know that nothing can modify that.  A [mcve] of source that reproduces this would be interesting.  Does it help to use -O3 for full optimization?

Thank you for your quick answers, especially at guru Mr. Cordes! I tried a lot, until now nothing helped. I work on a MWE. As I said, its not acceptable!

Your "MWE" is still only the compiler's output, not the C or C++ input that compiled to this loop.  The point of a reproducible example is that other people can try the code on their own system or https://godbolt.org/ and see the same problem (missed optimization) that you're trying to fix.  So we can see if a different compiler version makes a difference, or what changes in the source make it not happen.  It doesn't have to be a complete program that does anything useful, just a function is fine since we're just looking at the asm.

BTW, if you write the source differently, you can save instructions and avoid the pxor entirely.  movemask(vec) != 0xffff (pmovmskb / cmp+jne) is cheaper than movemask(~vec) != 0  (pxor / pmovmskb / test+jne).  CMP with an immediate can still macro-fuse with JCC like TEST can into a single compare-and-branch uop.  That still leaves the problem of the memory-source pcmpeqb; you aren't taking the address of a __m128i local, are you?

This was the decisive hint: movemask(vec) != 0xffff. I'll update the question. You could make this an answer? Thank you, Mr. Cordes!!

It's not the answer to your GCC missed-optimization question (about enregistering values).  It's a good idea when it's possible to avoid needing the constant in the first place, but there are cases where you do need vector constants.  If GCC has a bug where it's not keeping them in registers, that should be identified and fixed.

IDK man, your C++ source isn't reproducing the missed-optimization you were talking about where GCC keeps reloading from memory. https://godbolt.org/z/91o8on9nM  .  I tried a couple older GCC versions, too, but I didn't notice that missed optimization.  If you're only seeing it with some older version but not current trunk, it's already fixed and shouldn't get reported.

Also, you used __m128i lead = _mm_set1_epi8(24); at global scope, so that's in .bss, copied from .rodata in a static constructor.  Don't do that.  Use an array if it needs to be runtime-variable and _mm_load_si128 from it at the top of the function.  Since its a non-const global, any stores in your loop could change its value (as far as GCC knows), which could explain the reloads.  But no, your actual asm shows loading from .LC41, and GCC's naming scheme only uses .LC for constants, not .bss.  So your "MCVE" is super different from the asm you showed.

BTW, the modern way to do bit-scan is C++20 std::countl_zero (which can compile to lzcnt if available) or std::countr_zero (tzcnt, which runs the same as bsf for non-zero inputs, so the compiler can sometimes avoid extra branching even without BMI1 if you use it on a value known to be non-zero.)  You might get more efficient asm from using a BSR intrinsic directly like you're doing, though, for a version that can't use lzcnt.  If you could, then it's better on AMD CPUs, and about the same on Intel.  But you'd have to do like i - 15 + (31-lzcnt( (uint32_t)mask )).

I didn't manage it with godbolt either. This is a member function of a medium-sized class. As a global func, it would be fine. The lead is inside the function and dynamic. No lzcnt. I use gcc 13.1, deliberately limit to SSE2 and cpp_std=c++11. With minimal switches, nothing changes. But a code rearrangement solved the problem! A test for a special case with a constant. The main loop goes straight trough. My lessons learned: 1. Keep it simple. 2. Never trust the compiler when it counts. Thank you again for pointing me in the right direction!
